# Show Form Field if Drop Down Item is Selected Using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to create a dropdown field where if the "Other" item is selected, then a "Please Specify" text box appears. The below works with just one dropdown select field, but as soon as I add the second select field, it no longer works.

Here's what I have that doesn't seem to work:

CSS...

```
#techother{display:none;}
#lmsother{display:none;}
```

Body...

```
<p>Chose Your Browser: <select name = "Browser" required>
        <option value = "">-- Select an Option --</option>
        <option value = "1">IE</option>
        <option value = "2">FF</option>
        <option value = "3">Safari</option>
        <option value = "4">Opera</option>
        <option value = "5">Other</option>
        </select>
    </p>
  <div id="browserother">
    <p>Please Specify: <label id="browserlabel"><input name="Other Browser" type="text" placeholder="Other Browser" size="50" /></label></p>
    </div>

    <p>Operating System: <select name = "OS" required>
        <option value = "">-- Select an Option --</option>
        <option value = "Win">Windows</option>
        <option value = "ios">iOS</option>
        <option value = "otheros">Other</option>
        </select>
    </p>
  <div id="osother">
    <p>Please Specify: <label id="oslabel"><input name="Other OS" type="text" placeholder="Other OS" size="50" /></label></p>
  </div>
```

Script...

```
  <script>
$('form select[name=Browser]').change(function(){
  if ($('form select option:selected').val() == '5'){
    $('#browserother').show();
  }else{
    $('#browserother').hide();
  }
});

$('form select[name=OS]').change(function(){
  if ($('form select option:selected').val() == 'otheros'){
    $('#osother').show();
  }else{
    $('#osother').hide();
  }
});
</script>
```

Any way to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/ecZrE/

You mixed up some things in the selectors. Use

```
$('p select[name=Browser]')
```

instead of

```
$('form select[name=Browser]')
```

since there is no form element. But your snippet is incomplete anyway.

Another wrong selector is

```
$('form select option:selected')
```

because you forgot to specify the select element.

Answer (score 9):

Try this DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2pM3n/1/

```
$('select[name=Browser]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '5') {
        $('#browserother').show();
    } else {
        $('#browserother').hide();
    }
});

$('select[name=OS]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'otheros') {
        $('#osother').show();
    } else {
        $('#osother').hide();
    }
});
```