# show input field once drop down is selected in Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

Hi guys I am using Wordpress Contact Form 7 plugin and trying to achieve: **Show text field if drop down "Other" is selected**

[image: Drop down menu items]

I am using following raw JS for now through Visual composer in Wordpress Page after adding `dropdown` as id in Contact Form 7:

```
var x = document.getElementById("dropdown");
if(x.value = "Other") {
 alert('Enter your js here!');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Form Field if Drop Down Item is Selected Using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088381/show-form-field-if-drop-down-item-is-selected-using-jquery)

Comment: As I mentioned I am using Contact Form 7 (Wordpress plugin) where I don't have control over HTML of contact form

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-this-is-how-to-showhide-fields-with-jquery

Comment: Yup that's working thanks Lalji

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking for a simpler solution. In contact form 7, you can simply add inline JavaScript.

JavaScript added to the form builder will be rendered on the front-end as long as you do not add blank lines within the script.

Here is the copy from a CF7 form editor:

```
<label> Your Name (required)
[text* your-name] </label>

<label> Your Email (required)
[email* your-email] </label>

<label> Your Favorite Color
[select drop-down-menu id:FavoriteColorDropDown "Pink" "Red" "Purple" "Other"] </label>

<label id="EnterFavoriteColorLabel"> Please Specify Your Favorite Color
[text favorite-color] </label>

[submit "Send"]

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// Hide the favorite-color text field by default
document.getElementById("EnterFavoriteColorLabel").style.display = 'none';
// On every 'Change' of the drop down with the ID "FavoriteColorDropDown" call the displayTextField function
document.getElementById("FavoriteColorDropDown").addEventListener("change", displayTextField);
  function displayTextField() {
    // Get the value of the selected drop down
    var dropDownText = document.getElementById("FavoriteColorDropDown").value;
    // If selected text matches 'Other', display the text field.
    if (dropDownText == "Other") {
      document.getElementById("EnterFavoriteColorLabel").style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("EnterFavoriteColorLabel").style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Hope that helps.

If you are interested in reading more or extending the same for radio buttons, I recently published an article with more code samples and examples [here](http://millionclues.com/tutorials/conditionally-display-fields-in-contact-form-7-with-simple-javascript/).